# Perl slices and references

Tags: perl, slice

I created the following slice:

```
my %hash = ( a => 1, b => 2, c => 3 );
my @backslashed_slice_result = \@hash{qw(a b c)};
#  $backslashed... <-- originally I wrote this is a scalar, see below.
```

I expected this to produce an array reference to an array populated by the hash slice, equivalent to:

```
my $arrayref_containing_slice = [ @hash{qw(a b c)} ]; # [1, 2, 3]
```

But actually is doing something more like:

```
my @mapped_list_of_values_to_refs = map { \$hash{$_} } qw(a b c); # (\1, \2, \3)
```

The main point I could find in the [documentation](http://perldoc.perl.org/perldata.html#Slices) that describes this behaviour is the statement:

> A slice accesses several elements of a list, an array, or a hash
>   simultaneously using a list of subscripts.

So is `\@hash{qw(a b c)}` actually a list slice, rather than a hash slice? I am surprised at the reference being taken of the values of the hash, instead of of the resulting array of values. What is it about the syntax that causes perl to apply the leading `\` to the values of the hash?

Answer (score 3):

Two points:

First, a hash slice does not produce an array, it produces a list of the sliced hash elements.

Second, using \ on a list produces a list of references to the elements of the first list.

Comment: I wasn't aware of the list reference behaviour. Here's the relevant [documentation](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlref.html#Making-References) quote:

_Taking a reference to an enumerated list is not the same as using square brackets--instead it's the same as creating a list of references!_

        `@list = (\$a, \@b, \%c);
        @list = \($a, @b, %c);      # same thing!`

The `\@` syntax looks exactly like taking a reference to an array - so combining this with hash slices makes it pretty confusing!

Comment: @AdamMillerchip The sigils can be confusing. Maybe this bit from [perldata](http://perldoc.perl.org/perldata.html#Slices) will help: "If you're confused about why you use an '@' there on a hash slice instead of a '%', think of it like this. The type of bracket (square or curly) governs whether it's an array or a hash being looked at. On the other hand, the leading symbol ('$' or '@') on the array or hash indicates whether you are getting back a singular value (a scalar) or a plural one (a list)."

Comment: @ThisSuitIsBlackNot That explanation is clear and is what I had in mind but the list reference behaviour is not consistent with it. If we further deduce that preceding backslash means 'get a reference to', then `\@array` means 'reference to array' and `\@hashslice{...}` means 'reference to array' too, except that it doesn't. :-)

Comment: @Adam I see why it's confusing, although your logic is a little off. If `\@hashslice{...}` means "reference to array," what does the `{...}` block mean? I would expect that to generate a syntax error. Also, people deduce the same thing even without the reference: if `@foo` is an array, then `@foo{bar}` must also be an array, right? Just keep in mind that slices are lists, not arrays, despite the `@`. And just to reiterate, I'm not arguing that the sigils are straightforward; they've actually been [changed in Perl 6](http://design.perl6.org/Differences.html#Sigils) to be more intuitive.